# I am trying to upload an image but unable to upload JPG image in robot framework?

Tags: robotframework

I am working for a project where i need to upload image(JPEG) from system but whenever i write script, it will through error "element is not intractable".

**code**

*** Settings ***

```
#Suite Setup   Connect To Database   pymysql   ${DB_NAME}    ${DB_USER}      ${DB_PASSWORD}    

${DB_HOST}    ${DB_PORT} 

Suite Teardown   Disconnect From Database     

Library  SeleniumLibrary

Library    DateTime

Library    Dialogs

Library    String

Library  DatabaseLibrary

Library  OperatingSystem
```

*** Variables ***

```
${URL}  *****

${BROWSER}  chrome 

${TXTBOX_USERNAME}  xpath://*[@id='content']/app-login/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/input

${txtbox_password}  xpath://*[@id='content']/app-login/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/input

${BUTTON_LOGIN}    xpath://*[@id='content']/app-login/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/div[4]/a

${ERROR}  Bad credentials

${DATE_OF_BIRTH}    10-14-1993

${DATE_OF_BIRTH1}   10-14-1993

${element}        xpath:/html/body/ion-modal/app-add-customer-popup/ion-content/div/div/div/form/div/div/div[7]/div/a/img

${DB_NAME}        demo_digital1

${DB_USER}        ***

${DB_PASSWORD}    ***

${DB_HOST}        ***

${DB_PORT}        ***

${FILE_PATH}    C:/Users/rahul.yadav/Workspace1/Satya_Project/Images/flower photo.jpg
```

*** keywords ***

```
${application form no}=    Get Value    //*[@id='content']/app-deal-details/div[2]/div/app-source-details/div/form/div[1]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/input
```

${deal no}=  Get Value  xpath://*[@id='content']/app-deal-details/div[2]/div/app-source-details/div/form/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/input

```
${Branch}=  Get Value     xpath://*[@id='content']/app-deal-details/div[2]/div/app-source-details/div/form/div[1]/div/div/div/div[4]/div/ng-select/div/div/div[3]/input
```

${Generated By}=  Get Value    xpath://*[@id='content']/app-deal-details/div[2]/div/app-source-details/div/form/div[1]/div/div/div/div[5]/div

```
${Relationship Officer}=   Get Value    xpath://*[@id='content']/app-deal-details/div[2]/div/app-source-details/div/form/div[1]/div/div/div/div[6]/div/input

${Line Manager1}=        Get Value    xpath://*[@id='content']/app-deal-details/div[2]/div/app-source-details/div/form/div[1]/div/div/div/div[7]/div

${Horizontal}=   Get Value    xpath:/html/body/ion-modal/app-add-customer-popup/ion-content/div/div/div/form/div/div/div[6]/div/input 

   ${Vertical}=    Get Value    xpath:/html/body/ion-modal/app-add-customer-popup/ion-content/div/div/div/form/div/div/div[6]/div/input
    
   [Return]         ${application form no}   ${deal no}  ${Branch}  ${Generated By}  

 ${Relationship Officer}   ${Line Manager1}    ${Horizontal}    ${Vertical}
```

Select From Dropdown By Pressing Keys

```
  [Arguments]    ${locator}    ${option}

Click Element    xpath:/html/body/ion-modal/app-add-customer-popup/ion-content/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/ion-select

Press Keys    xpath:/html/body/ion-modal/app-add-customer-popup/ion-content/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/ion-select    ENTER
```

Date of Birth

```
 [Arguments]    ${date_of_birth}

       Click Element   xpath://*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-dedupe-customer/form/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div/input

 Select Date from Picker    ${date_of_birth}

Select Date from Picker

[Arguments]    ${date}

 ${year}   Split String    ${date}    -

${month}    Set Variable    ${year[1]}

${day}    Set Variable    ${year[2]}

Input Text  xpath://*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-dedupe-customer/form/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div/input               ${year}
   
   Input Text   xpath://*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-dedupe-customer/form/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div/input    ${month}


Input Text   xpath://*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-dedupe-customer/form/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div/input        ${day}
```

Date of Birth1

```
 [Arguments]    ${DATE_OF_BIRTH1}

       Click Element   xpath://*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-customer-basic-details/form/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[9]/div/input

Select Date from Picker1    ${DATE_OF_BIRTH1}

Select Date from Picker1

[Arguments]    ${date}
 
${year}   Split String    ${date}    -

${month}    Set Variable    ${year[1]}

${day}    Set Variable    ${year[2]}

Input Text  xpath://*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-customer-basic-details/form/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[9]/div/input    ${year}
   
Input Text   xpath://*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-customer-basic-details/form/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[9]/div/input   ${month}

Input Text   xpath://*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-customer-basic-details/form/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[9]/div/input    ${day}
```

*** Test Cases ***

Connect to Database

```
  Connect To Database   pymysql   ${DB_NAME}    ${DB_USER}    ${DB_PASSWORD}    ${DB_HOST}    ${DB_PORT} 


Execute SQL Query

 ${outputlog} =  Execute Sql String    SELECT * FROM SEC_USER_M WHERE USER_ID = '***' ;

    Log    ${outputlog}
```

Verify Login Pass-Correct username and password

```
 Open browser    ${URL}   ${BROWSER}
  
 Set Selenium Implicit Wait    1s
      
  Maximize Browser Window
  
                  
 
  Sleep  2    

  Input Text    ${txtbox_username}    ***
 
  Input Password    ${txtbox_password}    ***
 
 Sleep  2

  Click Element   ${BUTTON_LOGIN}    
  
  
  Sleep  2
```

**Click on Lead Processing**

```
Set Focus To Element    xpath://*[@id='content']/app-welcomes/div/div/app-omnifin-fin-dashboard/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div
   
Click Element   xpath://*[@id='content']/app-welcomes/div/div/app-omnifin-fin-dashboard/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div

  Sleep  2
```

Click on New Lead

```
 Set Focus To Element   xpath://*[@id='v-pills-one']/div[1]/a

  
 Click Element           xpath://*[@id='v-pills-one']/div[1]/a
  
  Sleep  2
```

Dedupe

```
   Set Focus To Element    xpath://*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-dedupe-customer/form/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/select



   Select From List By Value  xpath://*[@id="content"]/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-dedupe-customer/form/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/select        A    

**First Name**

 

   Set Focus To Element    xpath://*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-dedupe-customer/form/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/input


  Input Text              xpath://*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-dedupe-customer/form/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/input    ***
```

Last Name

```
Set Focus To Element   xpath://*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-dedupe-customer/form/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div/input
```

Input Text             xpath://*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-dedupe-customer/form/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div/input    YADAV

Date of Birth

```
Date of Birth                  ${DATE_OF_BIRTH}

Set Focus To Element           xpath://*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-dedupe-customer/form/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div/input

  Input Text                     xpath://*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-dedupe-customer/form/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div/input   ${DATE_OF_BIRTH}

 Wait Until Element Is Visible    xpath://*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-dedupe-customer/form/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div/input

 Scroll Element Into View         xpath://*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-dedupe-customer/form/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div/input 

 Click Element                    xpath://*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-dedupe-customer/form/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div/input
```

PAN No

```
   Set Focus To Element    xpath://*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-dedupe-customer/form/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[5]/div/input

 Input Text              xpath://*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-dedupe-customer/form/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[5]/div/input    ****
```

**Aadhar No**

```
Set Focus To Element    xpath://*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-dedupe-customer/form/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[6]/div/input

 Input Text              xpath://*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-dedupe-customer/form/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[6]/div/input    ****
```

**Constitution**

```
Set Focus To Element    xpath://*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-dedupe-customer/form/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[8]/div/select

 Select From List By Value    xpath://*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-dedupe-customer/form/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[8]/div/select    ***
```

**Mobile No**

```
Set Focus To Element    xpath://*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-dedupe-customer/form/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/input

 Input Text    xpath://*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-dedupe-customer/form/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/input    **********
```

**Email**

```
  Set Focus To Element    xpath://*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-dedupe-customer/form/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/input

  Input Text    xpath://*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-dedupe-customer/form/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/input    a@gmail.com
```

**Click on Search**

```
  Set Focus To Element    xpath://*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-dedupe-customer/form/div/div/div[2]/button[1]/span

Click Element    xpath://*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-dedupe-customer/form/div/div/div[2]/button[1]/span    

Sleep  3

#Click on Next
 
 #Click Element    xpath://*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-dedupe-customer/form/div/div/div[2]/button[2]/span
```

**Click on Customer**

```
Click Element    xpath://*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/ul/li[2]/span
```

**Customer Type**

```
Set Focus To Element    xpath://*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-customer-basic-details/form/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/ion-select

 Scroll Element Into View  xpath://*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-customer-basic-details/form/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/ion-select

 Select From List By Value    xpath://*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-customer-basic-details/form/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/ion-select    I
```

**Selection Type**

```
 Select From List By Value    xpath://*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-customer-basic-details/form/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/select        P
```

Sleep  2

**Enter Aadhar No**

```
#  Set Focus To Element    xpath://*[@id="content"]/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-customer-basic-details/form/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/input

  Input Text              xpath://*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-customer-basic-details/form/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/input    *****
```

**Enter Pan no**

```
  Input Text    xpath://*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-customer-basic-details/form/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/input    ****
```

**Enter First Name**

```
  Input Text    xpath://*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-customer-basic-details/form/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[5]/div/input    Rahul
```

**Enter Last Name**

```
 Input Text    xpath://*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-customer-basic-details/form/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[7]/div/input    Yadav
```

**`Gender`**

```
Select From List By Value    xpath://*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-customer-basic-details/form/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[8]/div/select    M
```

Select date of birth on customer

Date of Birth1                  ${DATE_OF_BIRTH1}

```
 Set Focus To Element           xpath://*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-customer-basic-details/form/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[9]/div/input

 Input Text                     xpath://*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-customer-basic-details/form/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[9]/div/input   ${DATE_OF_BIRTH1}

 Wait Until Element Is Visible    xpath://*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-customer-basic-details/form/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[9]/div/input

 Scroll Element Into View         xpath://*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-customer-basic-details/form/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[9]/div/input

  Click Element                    xpath://*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-customer-basic-details/form/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[9]/div/input
```

Select Constitution on customer

```
Select From List By Value    xpath://*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-customer-basic-details/form/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[10]/div/select    SALARIED
```

Enter Email

```
Input Text    xpath://*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-customer-basic-details/form/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[11]/div/input    reyanshyadav8287@gmail.com
```

Enter mobile no

```
Input Text    xpath://*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-customer-basic-details/form/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[12]/div/input    8178089068
```

upload photo

Sleep  3

Set Focus To Element        xpath://*[@id="content"]/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-customer-basic-details/form/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/ion-button

Scroll Element Into View    xpath://*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-customer-basic-details/form/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]

Choose File                xpath: //*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-customer-basic-details/form/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]        ${FILE_PATH}

Sleep  2

Click on next

Click Element    xpath://*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-customer-basic-details/form/div/div[2]/button

[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/utiox.png